# When is a Postgres function type-checked?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres allows you to specify function parameter types and a return type. When are these checked? When the function is created? When it's called? Or is it just an annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are checked for existence when the function is defined – you cannot define a function using non-existent types (that's why PostgreSQL has *shell types*).

The function body is only checked for syntax errors.

When the query is planned, PostgreSQL checks that the data types of the arguments and the return value match your query. If the argument types don't match exactly, [type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) kicks in and adds type casts.

Finally, at execution time PostgreSQL checks that the datum returned matches the function result data type.